# How can i get threshold value automatically

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Currently, I want to get the threshold value automatically, I have used  opencv cv::mean() to get the brightness of the image then apply the value into the threshold function, but the result is not I expected.

For the above image the threshold value is 195 which I manually set, but when used cv::mean() I get the value of 225 which is not the result I want. I also have tried THRESH_OTSU but the result also different.
`_brightnessCvS = cv::mean(_grayCvMat); m_dBright = _brightnessCvs.val[0];`

Is that any way auto detects threshold value to get the result same as the picture?

Answer (score 2):

I consider using mean value of only edge region instead of whole image.
(Of cause, this way require another heuristic threshold to detect edge region... but deciding this value may be easier than the original problem.)

```cpp
int main()
{
    //Load image as gray-scale
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread( "Gray.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( SrcImg.empty() )return 0;
    cv::imshow( "SrcImg", SrcImg );

    //Create Edge Region Only Mask
    cv::Mat Mask;
    {
        cv::morphologyEx(
            SrcImg, Mask, cv::MORPH_GRADIENT,
            cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT , cv::Size(3,3) )
        );

        //Here, threshold for "edge or not" is decided heuristically.
        double MinVal, MaxVal;
        cv::minMaxLoc( Mask, &MinVal, &MaxVal );
        cv::threshold( Mask, Mask, 0.25*(MinVal+MaxVal), 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
        cv::imshow( "Mask", Mask );
    }
    
    //Decide threshold as mean value of Masked region
    double Thresh = cv::mean( SrcImg, Mask )[0];
    cv::threshold( SrcImg, SrcImg, Thresh, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
    cv::imshow( "Result", SrcImg );
    std::cout << Thresh << std::endl;

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

To test this code, I cut out source image from your posted image by hand roughly, so, my source image would lost area near border.
But I don't think this will affect the results much.
And I got the threshold value `191.087`. This value looks close enough to yours.

This is binalized result:

[image]

**Note** : Needless to say, this simple method assumes that the values of the gradients at the boundaries (edges) between black and white are uniform.
Therefore, cannot be applied to general images as is.

Comment: Wow! Great Idea I may try it Thanks!

Comment: I have try with the original image but mine result get 201.+ something, its any parameter can change to achieve the result?

Comment: I also added the original image

Comment: When I use your added image, result becomes very bad. Then I found why. This is because the image has a vertical black line at x=1. Cutting out x>1 range, I got result value `198.503`. Although this value looks good yet, but Mask looks becoming to unenoughly. I think, this is because size of your new image is big and some edge is blurred.

Comment: I think, you can process the threshold deciding step on small(shrink) size image, to avoid the undesired affecting of blur. 
(It has the same meaning as increasing the kernel size of `morphologyEx`, relatively.)

Comment: Great Thanks for the advice, I will try explore on is that any way can process the blurring or noise function. I have try on small size image the result is better.